# HTML5 webstorage

Tags: html

Is it possible to give an offline HTML5 form to the end user like Excel file using storage mechanism?. So that he can fill the form and upload it to the J2ee based site.

In Excel this is possible. User can download the format of excel file, fills it and upload to the website. Later in servlet we read the contents and store them in DB.

Is same thing possible with HTML5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggestion required on HTML5 and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739145/suggestion-required-on-html5-and-java)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You have to build the application as an [offline application](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/). While the user is updating is data, you serialize it to the [webstorage](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/browser-storage/). As soon as you have [internet connectivity](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/workingoffthegrid.html), just send the serialized that to the server to be parsed.

Comment: I will explain my requrement with more clarity by considering offline file format as Excel (.xls) example. I will design an excel file with contents whcih I need input from user. I will give a link to download the excel file in web app. User can download the Excel. fills all values(filling may be in other computer). I will give provision to him to upload that filled excel file in the web app. I will read the excel file when he uploads it and finally will store in DB.This is very much possible if I use Exel format file. Is same thing possible with HTML5 using webstorage or any other feature.